# CUDA inplace algorithm for stream compaction

Tags: cuda, nvidia

The algorithm for stream compaction is pretty straight forward:

1. In a separate array, mark each element that should be kept with a 1, and all others with a 0.
2. Compute the prefix sum of this array.
3. At the index specified by the prefix sum, place the elements from the input array that are to be kept into the output array.

Now this is pretty easy to implement in CUDA. But let's assume that the input is the same as the output, and we want to compute it in-place. How would this work? I can't wrap my head around that. The only thing I can think of is to create a temporary array that holds the output before assigning it to the input variable, but that can hardly be called an in-place algorithm. Any ideas how to tackle this problem?

Comment: load chunk of items, grid synchronization, write selected items of chunk

Comment: cub's `DeviceSelect`  has overloads for inplace compaction. it uses a decoupled look-back scan approach